# ¿Como Ajustar un programa en Java a cualquier pantalla?

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola comunidad me encuentro en la necesidad, de saber como ajustar un panel de manera automática, sucede que cambie de monitor y mi proyecto se ajusto a mi pantalla anterior, por lo cual quiero saber, como podría ajustar mis Paneles a cualquier pantalla.

Comment: Como los tienes inicializados?

Comment: Investiga sobre los layouts

Comment: Los tengo de la siguiente manera:

public class Itaca extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     
    public Itaca() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.ButtonMenu_Principal.setSelected(true);
        new CambiaPanel(pnlPrincipal, new Paneles.PanelHome());
        
        
        
        
    }
    

pero sucede que dentro de mi JFrame voy llamando paneles que tengo echos de otra parte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza la clase `Toolkit` para averiguar datos sobre el hardware de tu ordenador. Como por ejemplo, la resolución.

La línea `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();` te da, por ejemplo, un *integer* con el valor del ancho en pixeles de tu monitor. Si quieres el punto medio, o un poco más a la izquierda, o más a la derecha... puedes operar con ese número entero.

El mismo código pero acabado en `getHeight()` te dará el alto en pixeles.

Con la clase `Toolkit` se puede acceder también al resto de hardware de tu ordenador. Como por ejemplo, para imprimir algo por impresora.

Comment: Gracias me funciono!